# How to check the first radio input generated by ng-repeat?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

Here's my code:

```
<div ng-repeat="color in item.color">
    <input id="{{color}}" name="color" type="radio" value="{{color}}" ng-model="$parent.chosenColor" />
    <label for="{{color}}">{{color}}</label>
</div>
```

It generates three radio inputs, as it should:

```
<div ng-repeat="color in item.color" class="ng-scope">
    <input class="ng-pristine ng-valid" id="beige" name="color" value="beige" ng-model="$parent.chosenColor" type="radio">
    <label class="ng-binding" for="beige">beige</label>
</div>
<div ng-repeat="color in item.color" class="ng-scope">
    <input class="ng-pristine ng-valid" id="black" name="color" value="black" ng-model="$parent.chosenColor" type="radio">
    <label class="ng-binding" for="black">black</label>
</div>
<div ng-repeat="color in item.color" class="ng-scope">
    <input class="ng-pristine ng-valid" id="white" name="color" value="white" ng-model="$parent.chosenColor" type="radio">
    <label class="ng-binding" for="white">white</label>
</div>
```

What I want is to have one of the inputs already checked when the page loads (preferably the first one). I've tried more approaches I can count and I'm getting out of my mind.
How can this be done?

Comment: can u show the function you are using to generate this html

Comment: It's just angular's ng-repeat. Nothing more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the appropriate value for your model in your controller:

```
$scope.chosenColor = $scope.item.color[0];
```

Comment: I could swear I've tried that... There must have been some spelling error. It works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: Dear downvoter, if you still here, how could I improve my answer?

Comment: For what it's worth, your answer couldn't be improved, because it was exactly what I needed to solve my problem.